# Homeomorphism on (a,b) an R in terms of discrete topology

Tags: general-topology

Are (a,b) and R homeomorphic, if they both have discrete topology?

Comment: Yes, since they have the same cardinality and any bijection between the two sets serves as a homeomorphism since all subsets of $(a, b)$ and all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are open in their respective topologies.

Comment: Thanks for your response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any bijection between spaces that have the discrete topology is a homeomorphism (all maps on a discrete space are continuous).